# whether $L^p$ harmonic function is constant for $0<p<1$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u$ be a harmonic function on $R^n$ such that $u \in L^p(R^n)$,where $0<p<1$.
I want to know whether $u$ is constant?

I know $u$ is constant iff $u$ is bounded above or bounded below and have no idea.

Comment: It seems this is answered on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117662/a-question-about-lp-integral-of-an-entire-function-on-mathbbc